# Creating Relationship in MS Access

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a Student table and a Course table. One student can be involved in many courses and a student can only pay the fee of the course which he is invloved. How can i create relationship for this problem.

Comment: What have you tried? I mean, this is a fairly simple case of making a query with the appropriate joins, which is well documented everywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediate table that will hold Students-to-Courses data, this table can have many rows for a given student like this: Studennt1-Course1, Student1-Course2, etc... the SQL to retrieve the courses of a given studen would be:

**SELECT Courses.Courses_id, Courses.Description FROM Courses
INNER JOIN Students-Courses ON Courses.Courses_id = Students-Courses.Courses_id
INNER JOIN Students ON Students-Courses.Student_id = Students.Student_id 
WHERE Courses.Course_id = 33**

The best thing would be to use only numerical ids in this intermediate table and those numerical ids to be the primary key on the Students and Courses tables respectively as an autonumeric column per instance. The intermediate table would be like: id_students_courses (autonumeric), students_id, courses_id. The id_students_courses would be the primary key for the relationship table.

Comment: Problem Solved . Thank You Very Much..........